# Keep a Running Tally of Duplicated Records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

There have been many similar questions asked to this but I couldn't find a way to do exactly what I'm trying to do. I need to keep a running tally of duplicate entries in a column, and report that number in an "Owner Number" column. Example below:

```
Roll Number  |  Owner Name  |  Owner Number
000001       |  Patrick H.  |  1
000001       |  Paula H.    |  2
000002       |  Fred R.     |  1
000003       |  Chris P.    |  1
000003       |  Kayla A.    |  2
000003       |  Phil J.     |  3
```

In other words, I just need to count how many owners each roll has up to that point, not just a total number of owners for each roll. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a subquery or two and a @variable

I.e. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c2fa/7

```
SELECT

  -- Re-selected at this level to tidy up the calculation fields
  f.rollNumber,
  f.ownerName,
  f.ownerNumber

FROM (
  SELECT

    d.rollNumber,
    d.ownerName,
    -- If the current roll number equals the previous, increment, else reset to 1
    @i := IF(d.rollNumber=@last,@i+1,1) AS ownerNumber,
    -- Sets @last to be == the "current" one for use on next row
    @last := d.rollNumber

  FROM
  (
      -- Get the raw data ordered by roll number
      SELECT

          LPAD(rollNumber,6,'0') rollNumber,
          ownerName

      FROM someTable
      -- Reorder / filter as much as you like, but always rollNumber ASC first
      ORDER BY
          rollNumber ASC,
          ownerName ASC
  ) d,(
      -- Set up the variables we will need shortly
      SELECT @i:=0,@last:=0
  ) v
) f;
```

Comment: Huge thanks, this worked brilliantly! Still learning the variable side of MySQL and this really helped put it into perspective.

Comment: Good to hear, it can be a bit of a headache at first but used well they can open up so many more possibilities within your queries.  With things like this you just need to keep in mind the order of what you are doing - once you are at the top level you can reorder any way you like though without the ownerNumber changing as at that point it is fixed :) (try adding an `ORDER BY f.ownerName DESC` to the end for example)

Answer (score 1):

Mysql doesn't support window functions but it can be done with variables:

```
SET @num=0;
SET @roll='';
SELECT `Roll Number`,`Owner Name`,`Owner Number`
FROM
(
SELECT `Roll Number`,
`Owner Name`,
(CASE WHEN @roll=`Roll Number` 
                            THEN @num:=@num+1 ELSE
                            @num:=1 END) as `Owner Number`,
@roll:=`Roll Number`
FROM table1
  ) as q;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/788a4/5